# uniform one-sided van der Corput inequality

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

Is the following true (and if yes, where the best proof is written?)?

For any $c>0$ for large enough positive integers $N$ we have $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \cos(k^2t)\geqslant -cN$ for all real $t$?

Hm, if true, it should be hard: it allows to get signs of certain Gauss type sums, for example.

Comment: It is hard to believe that the Gaus-sums have nonnegative real part... Maple shows that $\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}\exp(2 \pi i \frac{p}{q} k^{2})$ has negative real part for $q=5$ and $p=2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is negative.

As you said if you take $\frac{t}{2\pi}$ to be a rational number, say $\frac{p}{q}$ then  it converges to the Gaus-sums:
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \cos(k^{2} t) = \Re \frac{1}{q} \sum_{k=0}^{q-1} \exp\left( 2 \pi i \cdot \frac{p}{q} k^{2}\right)
$$
Now if you take $t=\frac{4 \pi}{5}$ (i.e., $p=2, q=5$) I think it should no be difficult to show that the latter sum is a negative number $< - 0.4$ (even without taking the real part).